# Deploy GWT menu missing in Luna (Eclipse 4.4)

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

In the GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.3 it was possible to deploa yor web application via a menu.
http://prntscr.com/4wmtjj

But the GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.4 does no more support this feature.
http://prntscr.com/4wmtjj

How can I get this feature also in Eclipse 4.4 Luna?

Best regards
Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

Try the new community beta release version, has better options and support for SDBG:

https://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/